# Using await within a Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

There seems something inherently wrong with having to define a Promise's callback as asynchronous:

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  const value = await somethingAsynchronous();
  if (value === something) {
    return resolve('It worked!');
  } else {
    return reject('Nope. Try again.');
  }
});
```

This is apparently an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and there are coding [problems which can arise from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/using-async-await-inside-new-promise-constructor#43050114). I understand that it becomes easier to fail to catch errors here, even when placing `await` statements inside `try`/`catch` blocks.

My first question is, what's the best way to code something like this, when one wants to forward a Promise with different resolve/reject values? With then/catch? I.e.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  somethingAsynchronous().then(value => {
    if (value === something) {
      return resolve('It worked!');
    } else {
      return reject('Nope. Try again.');
    }
  }); // errors would now be propagated up
});
```

Or do you just take it out the Promise constructor altogether as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/using-async-await-inside-new-promise-constructor#43050114)?

```
async function outerFunction() {
  const value = await somethingAsynchronous();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (value === something) {
      return resolve('It worked!');
    } else {
      return reject('Nope. Try again.');
    }
  });
}
```

But what if you have several await statements in the outerFunction(), i.e. a linear code block calling several asynchronous functions. Would you then have to create and return a new Promise every time?

But then how do you account for code such as this?

```
async function outerFunction() {
  if (someSynchronousCheck()) {
    return 'Nope. Try again.' // another reject case
  }

  const value = await somethingAsynchronous();
  // ...
}
```

I have the feeling that I'm making this more complicated than it should be. I'm trying to avoid nesting callbacks/chaining then/catch blocks without creating more problems in the future.

My final question is, why is the callback passed to a Promise not inherently `async`? It is already wrapped within a promise and expects the resolve/reject functions to be called asynchronously.

Comment: Always keep in mind, essentially the _only_ time `new Promise` is needed is if you are interoperating with a different API that uses callbacks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You do this:

```
async function outerFunction() {
  const value = await somethingAsynchronous();
  if (value === something) {
    return 'It Worked!';
  }
  throw Error('Nope. Try again.');
}
```

Using `async` wraps the result of `outerFunction` with a Promise.

If you want that wrapping promise to resolve to something, just return it from the `async` function. If you want the wrapping promise to be rejected, throw an error inside the `async` function.

> But then how do you account for code such as this?

```
async function outerFunction() {
  if (someSynchronousCheck()) {
    throw Error('Nope. Try again.');
  }

  const value = await somethingAsynchronous();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That last paragraph was exactly the answer I needed. I was trying to figure out how to 'reject' something from inside an async function.

Comment: "Using async wraps the result of outerFunction with a Promise." -- thanks!

Answer (score 31):

`new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { ... })` is relatively new antipattern. It results in creating 2 promise objects instead of 1, uncaught errors that happen inside constructor cannot be caught with `try..catch` and result in unhandled rejection.

Considering that promise asynchronous code can be handled with `async..await`, current use case for `Promise` constructor is non-promise asynchronous code, e.g.:

```
new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
```

When `Promise` constructor contains synchronous code or involves other promises, a promise should be constructed with `async` function. A drop-in replacement is `async` IIFE:

```
return (async (resolve, reject) => {
  const value = await somethingAsynchronous();
  if (value === something) {
    return 'It worked!';
  } else {
    throw 'Nope. Try again.';
  }
})();
```

If the need for `Promise` constructor still presents when being used together with `async`, `Promise` constructor should be moved down in hierarchy so it won't wrap any `async` function.

> My final question is, why is the callback passed to a Promise not inherently async? It is already wrapped within a promise and expects the resolve/reject functions to be called asynchronously.

`async` function isn't just a function that is executed asynchronously, it returns another promise that is supposed to be utilized - or at least handled with `catch`. `Promise` isn't supposed to utilize a promise that is returned from constructing function.

The constructor can resolve on same tick and doesn't necessarily have to be asynchronous.

```
Promise.resolve(1);
```

is similar to

```
Promise(resolve => resolve(1))
```

and not to

```
Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also chain the promises yourself by simply doing this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  somethingAsynchronous().then((value) => {
      if (value === something) {
        return resolve('It worked!');
      } else {
        return reject('Nope. Try again.');
      }
  }, (error) => { reject(error); });
});
```

I've been using this for some time and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove `async` from the code I copied from the op. (updated)